# Request Handler Opc Ua Server .NET

Tags: .net, server, request, handler, opc-ua

I'm developing an Opc Ua Server based on the one which is on the Opc Ua Foundation Repository. The [SampleServer](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/blob/e100ac787507988da95223a031af76fe57b5e11d/Samples/Opc.Ua.Sample/SampleServer.cs) file hasn't an OnRead (or something like that) method and I want add one but I don't understand how to do.

I can't see on the inherited classes a method that suited for me. Whit that method I'd like to handle a request by adding a tag on the structure if it isn't.

Is someone able to help me? The SampleServer.cs inherited the ReverseConnectServer and it inherited the StandardServer Class.